# Efficient Algorithm for LU-Factorization of Modified Matrix with Last Column Alteration If We Have Its Not-Modified LU-Factorization

Tags: matrix, numerics, matrix-factorization

Suppose that we have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$. We have its LU-factorization as $A=LU$ (or $PA=LU$  that $P$ is a permutation matrix). Now assume we change the last column of matrix $A$ and denote the new matrix as $A^\prime$. What is an efficient algorithm to find the LU-factorization of $A^\prime$ as $P^\prime A^\prime=L^\prime U^\prime$. If we look at the factorization process (Guassian elimination and partial pivoting), we can obviously find out that $P^\prime=P$ and $L^\prime=L$. Also $U$ and $U^\prime$ have the same entries except of in the last column. So only thing that we have to do, is to find the last column of $U^\prime$. What would be an efficient algorithm to find it?

Comment: Here is a similar previous question and detailed answer regarding the solution of multiple systems $Ax = b$ via LU decomposition where $A$ is perturbed by changing a single row. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/solve-rank-one-update-to-lu-using-plain-vanilla-lu-routine

Comment: You can take a look at the presentation "A Review of Sparsity and Stability in LU updates" by Michael Saunders https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/talks/12informs-saunders.pdf . Some key words that you want to search for and read about are eta-matrices (product form of the inverse), Forrest-Tomlin updates, Bartels-Golub updates . This is a well known problem in the optimization (particularly) simplex community. There are a lot of resources available online.